# Creating views with group by not grouping properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, view, psql

I have data that looks like Music92838, Entertainment298928, SPORTS2837 etc. in my Event_type column, and I'm trying to create a view that groups the number of performances by event_type

I tried to do

```
CREATE VIEW Performances_Type_Cnt
 AS SELECT regexp_replace(E.event_type, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') AS Event_Type,
  COUNT(*)
 FROM Event_Type E, Performance P
WHERE E.event_id = P.event_id 
GROUP BY Event_Type;
```

Using regex to only select characters, and then group by Music, Sports etc in the Group By Event_type. But something isn't working as in my results I'm getting

```
  event_type   | count
---------------+-------
 MUSIC         |     1
 SPORTS        |     5
 MUSIC         |     8
 MUSIC         |     3
```

where Music appears more than once in event_type, which isn't the correct result.

Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Not an expert in postgresql, but I would try to change the alias "Event_Type" to something different, maybe something inside psql is getting confused as the column name and alias name only differ in case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is that Postgres allows column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  So, it is confused as to whether the `EVENT_TYPE` comes from the table or the alias.  One simple solution is to use positional notation:

```
CREATE VIEW Performances_Type_Cnt AS
    SELECT regexp_replace(E.event_type, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') AS Event_Type,
           COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM Event_Type E JOIN
         Performance P
         ON E.event_id = P.event_id 
    GROUP BY 1;
```

I made some other changes:

- Replaced the implicit join with an explicit `JOIN`.  This is the standard way to write joins in SQL.
- Added a column alias for `COUNT(*)`.